# State is not updating in my REACT component class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-state

So I have a series of components  a slider, 3 buttons for long, medium and short and a Go! button.
here is a screencap just so ye can visualise the UI

[image]

i have a component class for the slider and the 3 Long short and medium buttons. all of which share state values.
The state values are the current number on the slider.., and a set of true/false values based on whether the long/short/medium buttons are selected or not.

So for example in the screenshot we can see long is selected whilst medium and short are not...
so in the state this would look like

```
Long = true
Medium = false
short = false
```

So the state values of the limit slider and the 3 buttons get passed to the Go!  button as props

All i wish to do with the go button is print out the state every time i click it.

But the problem is the states don't update at all when i change the slider or click a different button and i cant figure out why...

Here is the source code commented for the first class (Slider and 3 Buttons)

```
class User_Preference_Params extends Component {
  // contructor containing the current val of slider and the button stats (which are true false values)
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentValue: 30,
      button_State: { long: false, medium: true, short: false }
    };
  }
  // these are onclick functions that reset the state any time the long medium short buttons are clicked
  longClicked() {
    this.setState({
      button_State: {
        long: true,
        medium: false,
        short: false
      }
    });
  }

  mediumClicked() {
    this.setState({
      button_State: {
        long: false,
        medium: true,
        short: false
      }
    });
  }

  shortClicked() {
    this.setState({
      button_State: {
        long: false,
        medium: false,
        short: true
      }
    });
  }

  // this func gets the current value of the slider on change
  setCurrentValue(new_Value) {
    this.setState({
      currentValue: new_Value
    });
  }

  render() {
    function valuetext(value) {
      // getValue(value);
      return `${value}objects`;
    }

    function getValue(value) {
      return value;
    }

    return (
      // returning my slider and buttons
      <div className="main">
        <div className="slider">
          <Typography id="discrete-slider" gutterBottom>
            Limit
          </Typography>
          <Slider
            defaultValue={30}
            getAriaValueText={valuetext}
            aria-labelledby="discrete-slider"
            valueLabelDisplay="auto"
            step={1}
            marks
            min={1}
            max={50}
            onChange={() => this.getCurrentValue(getValue)}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="Pref_Timeform">
          <FormControl component="fieldset">
            <RadioGroup
              row
              aria-label="position"
              name="position"
              defaultValue="top"
            >
              <FormControlLabel
                value="top"
                control={<Radio color="primary" />}
                label="Long"
                labelPlacement="top"
                onClick={() => this.longClicked()}
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                value="start"
                control={<Radio color="primary" />}
                label="Medium"
                labelPlacement="top"
                onClick={() => this.mediumClicked()}
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                value="bottom"
                control={<Radio color="primary" />}
                label="Short"
                labelPlacement="top"
                onClick={() => this.shortClicked()}
              />
            </RadioGroup>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
        {/* // here i pass the states as props to the button */}
        <div className="Button">
          <User_Preference_Button
            currentValue={this.state.currentValue}
            button_State={this.state.button_State}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the code for the button class

```
class User_Preference_Button extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: this.props.currentValue,
      button_State: this.props.button_State
    };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="send_Container">
        <Button
          className="go_Button"
          variant="outlined"
          // here is the onlcikc that is suppost to log the states whcn i click the  Go! button
          onClick={() => {
            console.log(this.state.value, this.state.button_State);
          }}
        >
          Go!
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Ive a feeling it might have to do with how ive instantiated the functions for updating the states.. But im pretty stuck, would appreciate any help for newbie!

Comment: Just FWIW, `getCurrentValue` is an odd name for a method that **sets** a value. :-) Really confused me at first.

Comment: What values do the short, medium, and long buttons represent?

Comment: Three things, the User_Preference_Button can be a functional component, setting a new state there, won't watch the state changes in your User_Preference_Params component, just keep the User_Preference_Button as props and they will log all the changes, second: you're not binding your functions in the constructor, you need to do that, third thing by convention underscores for naming react components are not common, so try to use always UserPreferenceButton this naming convention to keep things readable.

Comment: You are setting the state to the value of the function, not calling it. Also I don't see anywhere where you render your state at all... and you aren't updating the state in the parent component but that's what you're logging? This is all very confusing.

Comment: So in the context of my project @T.J.Crowder when I click long, itll display info over a longer period of time, the same goes for medium and short. and sorry about the bad labels for the setter im all over the place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're setting the slider's new value, you're not doing anything to update the state flags for the buttons. While you *could* fix that where you set the new value (in `getCurrentValue`), I would't track the button states as their own flags at all. Instead, I'd infer the states from the current value of the slider, and I'd set the slider value (and thus the button state) when the user clicked the button.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
class Radio extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { name, label, buttonValue, value, setValue } = this.props;
        return (
            <label>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name={name}
                    checked={buttonValue === value}
                    onClick={() => setValue(buttonValue)}
                />
                {label}
            </label>
        );
    }
}

class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: 60
        };
        this.setValue = this.setValue.bind(this);
    }

    setValue(value) {
        this.setState({value});
    }
    
    render() {
        const { value } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    type="range"
                    min="30" 
                    max="90"
                    step="30"
                    value={value}
                    onChange={({target: {value}}) => this.setValue(+value)}
                />
                <Radio name="range" label="Short" buttonValue={30} value={value} setValue={this.setValue} />
                <Radio name="range" label="Medium" buttonValue={60} value={value} setValue={this.setValue} />
                <Radio name="range" label="Long" buttonValue={90} value={value} setValue={this.setValue} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```